# React - await until data fetches from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to fetch some JSON data and I have used async/await to hold the execution until data loading is ready. But React seems to completely ignore this and tries to render the component. I have written below simplified code to test this further and `setTimeout` is mimicking the API call delay.

```
console.log('global');
var index ="Data not loaded";

(async function fetchDataAsync(){
  console.log('async start');

  //mimcs loading data from API calls
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("Data loaded!"), 1000)
  });

  var index = await promise;
  console.log('async end');
  console.log(index);
})();

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      randomIndex:0
    }
    console.log('constructor');
  }
  render(){
    console.log('render');
    return (
      <div > 
        <p>{index}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The output shows *Data not loaded* and console shows below

*global*

*async start*

*constructor*

*render*

*async end*

*Data loaded!*

Is this how React supposed to work or am I missing something here? What would be the best place to put the API call so that it guarantees data will be loaded before the component mounts.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that async function doesn't hold up the **synchronous** processing of the code that function appears in. By which I mean, the order your code runs is:

1. **Start** running the `async` function up until the `await`
2. Create the `App` class
3. ...anything else you haven't shown after the `App` class; I'm guessing you use `App` somewhere...
4. Top-level code finishes
5. The timer fires
6. The promise waiting for the timer settles
7. The promise created by the `asycn` function call settles

Notice that 2-4 happened before 5-7 did.

What you'll want to do instead is either

1. Don't use `App` until you have the data, or
2. Give `App` a "waiting" state that it renders while waiting for the data

Each of those solutions is applicable to different situations, so you'll want to pick the one that works for your situation.

Comment: Thank you. I dig deep into `async/await` and could see that `await` doesn't have the power to hold the executions which are happening outside of the `async` function.

Comment: @AmilaChathuranga - Yup. :-) FWIW, I go into promises and `async` functions in some detail in Chapters 8 and 9 of my new book -- see my profile for links.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a React way of doing things, waiting for data to come before rendering.

Your code should be react-ive and it should trigger the component that data has arrived.

Here is how you can do this

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      randomIndex:0,
      data: '',
      loading: false
    }
    console.log('constructor');
  }
  
  fetchDataAsync = async () => {
    console.log('async start');
     this.setState({ loading: true });
    //mimcs loading data from API calls
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve("Data loaded!"), 1000)
    });

    var data = await promise;
    console.log('async end');
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({ loading: false, data });
  }

  render(){
    console.log('render');
    const { loading, data } = this.state;
    if(loading) return (<div className="loader">Loading ... </div>);
    if (!loading && data) {
      return (
        <div > 
          <p>{data}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: From where should I call `fetchDataAsync()` so that there won't be multiple API calls? Inside `componentDidMount()` seems logical but I am getting multiple calls

Comment: **EDIT -** Well I tried again and it works now. `componentDidMount()` seems to be the best place to call it